# Node JS get CSV

Tags: node.js

I have a project with `Node JS` in which I am collecting the information of a `JSON` by `http` using the `node-fetch` module.

This is the way I have found to use the node-fetch module with async, if it is possible to improve this function, suggestions are added, I am new to this module.

This is my `code` where I read the information:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

(async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        const headerDate = res.headers && res.headers.get('date') ? res.headers.get('date') : 'no response date';

        const users = await res.json();
        for(user of users) {
        console.log(`Got user with id: ${user.id}, name: ${user.name}`);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message); //can be console.error
    }
})();
```

**My problem**: how can I extract all the information to a CSV with a limit of lines ?, that is, the CSV has a limit of 10 lines (the limit can vary), if the JSON information occupies 30 lines, 3 CSVs would be created to store all the information. I have added the `json-2-csv` module, but I don't know how to use it or if this module is necessary or something else is better.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's a github issue where alternatives to `request` are listed -> https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143
I suggest you pick one from that list and try to integrate it in your app and if you're having problems doing so, update this question and show what you're trying to do :)

Comment: @eol Thanks for the info, I have used node-fetch module and updated my question.

Comment: Ok, and can you describe where the problem in splitting the `users` array into `csv` files is? You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @eol Thanks for the information is my premiere question in so. Well, the problem is that I don't know how to do it, I've seen that module but I don't know how to use it in this case or if that's the module I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { Parser } = require("json2csv");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require("fs");

const csvLimit = 3;

const getJson = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const responseJson = await response.json();
  return responseJson;
};

const jsonToCsv = async () => {
  const json = await getJson();
  const json2csvParser = new Parser();
  let i = 0,
    j = 0;
  while (j < json.length) {
    let csv = [];
    let temp = [];
    for (j = i * csvLimit; j < (i + 1) * csvLimit; j++) {
      temp.push(json[j]);
    }
    csv.push(json2csvParser.parse(temp));
    fs.writeFileSync(`file${(i * csvLimit) / 3}.csv`, csv);
    i++;
  }
};

jsonToCsv();
```

If you want only specific fields in the `csv` file, then you can pass the fields as parameter in this way.

`const json2csvParser = new Parser({fields})`

Comment: I'm getting the following error when testing the code and I don't know why: ```The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Array
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1517:5)
    at jsonToCsv (C:\Users\quality\Desktop\node\node-json\src\index.js:76:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)```

Comment: Have you installed the required modules and running the above code?

Comment: I am using the ``json-2-csv`` module, I think that may be why. But it seems that they do not work the same as can be adapted to this module?

Comment: Can you try installing the `json2csv` module?

Comment: I get the same error. Does that code work for you? I think the csv data is not reaching it

Comment: Its working for me nicely. Do one thing. Create a new file and paste the above code. Install modules `json2csv` and `node-fetch`. And then run the code. This should create 4 csv files (file0, file1, file2, file3).

Comment: If this doesn't work, you can try converting csv array to string. `fs.writeFileSync(....., csv.toString());`

Comment: Ok if it works like this, I don't understand why, thank you, now I'm going to edit the csv so that they display well. Now it is displayed with all the data in the first cell and with the quotation marks.

Comment: I didn't get you. Did it work for you? I mean do you have 3 records each in files 0, 1, 2 and 1 record in the file3 ?

Comment: Yes, all good when I added ``toString()``

Comment: Now I am trying to form the csv right, with each data in a cell and without the quotes

Comment: Glad it worked. Just a small change I have made. You can correct it.

Comment: What does the change do? Now, it removes the first three data and fills each csv with the fourth

Comment: The header was getting repeated for each record previously.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) package to extract the field names from the keys of the first record of the JSON and then used the [json-2-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-2-csv) package to convert from `JSON` to `CSV`.

```js
const converter = require("json-2-csv");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require("fs");
const flatten = require('flat');

const maxRecords = 3;

const getJson = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const responseJson = await response.json();
  return responseJson;
};

const convertToCSV = async () => {
  const json = await getJson();

  let keys = Object.keys(flatten(json[0]));

  let options = {
    keys: keys
  };

  converter.json2csv(json, json2csvCallback, options);
};

let json2csvCallback = function (err, csv) {

  if (err) throw err;

  const headers = csv.split('\n').slice(0,1);  
  const records = csv.split('\n').slice(0,);
  for(let i=1;i<records.length;i=i+maxRecords) {
    let dataOut = headers.concat(records.slice(i, i+3)).join('\n');
    let id = Math.floor(i/maxRecords)+1;
    fs.writeFileSync('data' + id + '.csv', dataOut)
  }
};

convertToCSV();
```

Here's one of the files opened in Excel.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to collect the titles from the json instead of putting them by hand ?, for example make a ``substr()`` before ``:``

Comment: How can I place each data in a column? I have tried to remove the commas but I only get it to skip the row

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the code I posted creates CSVs with all the values in separate columns - I'll add a screenshot of one of the files opened in Excel.

Comment: Ok yes, that's what I want to achieve but it doesn't show me like that. I will check the code but it should come out the same